# ¿Como puedo hacer un Toolbar con background transparente degradado?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, toolbar, color

Necesito lograr este efecto en el Toolbar:

[image: two muppets]

Este es el código que utilizo para llamar al `Toolbar`:

```
//...
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarMap);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColor));

getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.map_title);
myToolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back));
myToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

//...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crea un archivo en la carpeta drawable llamado `fade_bg.xml` y agregale esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#fff"
        android:endColor="#75ffffff"
        android:type="linear"
        />

</shape>
```

Esto lo que hace es crear un gradient con el color deseado y termiando con un blanco con opacidad.

Entonces le asignas background al elemento Toolbar:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:background="@drawable/fade_bg"


            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"                 
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Y este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]